# The correct way of showing a winform from a console app

Tags: winforms, console

First i used something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        logger.Controls.Add(new TextBox { Name = "tb" });
        logger.Show();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I got a form showed up, but not responsive at all. Then some googling told me to use Application.Run(), instead of Show() and then it worked. Now i wonder the explanation behind this.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no message loop in a console application.
Calling the Application.Run() begin to run a standard application message loop on the current thread.
See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know Application.Run() is more permitted than .show(), On that case you are using console. Application.Run() is more applicable than .show(). It could be use in just a form UI not in Console.

Hope it helps.